# gulp build task - concat and minify modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp

What is a good strategy for concatenating and minifying modules?

I want to take this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/satellizer/satellizer.min.js"></script>
etc...
```

And make it this:

```
<script src="js/all_bower_components.js"></script>
```

I am running this build process for my other js files, which are concatenated and minified into `main.js`, but that's easy because my folder structure for my own JS files is relatively predictable. But my bower components is not:

```
bower_components/
   angular/
       angular.js
       index.js
       other random js files which aren't the ones I need
   jquery/
       dist/
           jquery.js
       src/
           bunch of other crap
```

I am attempting it as such: Loop through all components and sub folders and simply search for `.js` files... but again, this could be including things I do not need like `index.js` in Angular:

```
gulp.task('modules', function() {
    return gulp.src(['bower_components/**/*.js'])
        .pipe(concat('modules.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js'));
});
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried `main-bower-files`?  this gulp plugin will capture all your base bower .js and .css by looking in your components' bower.json file for which files to grab (those listed as `main`).  you can override the defaults within your call to the plugin for any requirements that don't match their bower.json config.  i've found this very useful for bundling a vendor.js and vendor.css for a dependency-heavy app.

good luck!

Comment: This is pretty cool. For some reason I cannot `uglify` the concatenated JS files: `GulpUglifyError: unable to minify JavaScript` - yet uglify works for my other app js files

Comment: hmm, haven't encountered that -- i pass mine through uglify and it had no complaints -- make sure you use `gulpFilter` to get just the .js files for uglify (and potentially another filter for .css)

Comment: Would that just be `var jsFilter = filter('**/*.js');` then `return gulp.src(mainBowerFiles()).pipe(concat('modules.js')).pipe(jsFilter)... etc` ?

Comment: `var jsFilter = gulpFilter('**/*.js', {restore: true});` then after getting all bower, `.pipe(jsFilter)` -- yep, looks like you got it

Comment: I dont quite understand restore- why would I need to restore anything?

Comment: so you can then `.pipe(jsFilter.restore)` and then apply a similar `cssFilter` to do something else with the .css files :)

Comment: Also, to be clear, you need to first pipe through `jsFilter` THEN `concat('folder')`

Comment: yes, before any operations that should apply to just .js files, including sourcemaps etc.